# Why is my search function so slow + buggy sometimes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I originally had only one URL to fetch data, and my app worked flawlessly. But then I realized I had to use two different URLs to fetch the data I needed. So I changed the code a little bit. Everything is pretty much the same except for the `getData` function, where I used `map` to iterate the list of URLs and fetch the data. My app is really buggy now.

Problems:

When I search for a streamer, it sometimes never renders the result on the page. And the message `"search for your favorite streamer!"` doesn't disappear even though `this.state.value` is now NOT equal to `' '`. But when I change the input, it gets rendered out of nowhere.

It sometimes fails to render the data fetched and I get the `FinderResultContainer` rendered with no data in it. (No name, no img, no offline/online.)

What is exactly happening here? I feel like it is because I am not using the component life cycle methods. If so, then what exactly do I need to do? I am a total beginner, so I need to some guidance.

```
getData(value) {
let streamerData = [];
let streamerInfo = {};

let urls = ['https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/' + value, 'https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/users/' + value];

urls.map(function(each, index) {
  fetch(each).then((response) =>
  response.json()
).then((streamer) => streamerData.push(streamer)).then(()=>streamerInfo[index]=streamerData[index]).then(()=>{if (index === urls.length-1){this.setState({streamer: streamerData})}})},this)
}
```

https://codepen.io/brood915/pen/OWQpmy

Comment: since you're doing two ajax calls (I'm guessing they're ajax calls) you should probably use a function that waits for all of them to respond before doing the final thing.

Comment: Use promises because Web API are asynchronous in nature
Try https://caolan.github.io/async/ library

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` is asynchronous and returns a promise, so you don't know exactly when it'll be done. You can use `Promise.all()` to wait every promise to resolve and then work with the data (note that all promises will execute at the same time, so if you have a large list of urls you will be sending tons of request per second).

Edit: I saw your pen and simplified the code, this works fine to me.
No blank component here. Note that you only *need* to use `then` when returning promises.

```
getData(value, type) {
  let urls = [
    'https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/' + value,
    'https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/users/' + value
  ];

  const getJson = url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json());

  Promise.all(urls.map(getJson))
    .then(streamer => {
      if (type === "search") {
        this.setState({ streamer });
        console.log("searching")
      } else {
        console.log("displaying");
        this.getStreamer(streamer[0], streamer[1]);
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('Something went wrong...')
    })
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you so much. Is there any other way to achieve the same thing? I see that this has no support for I.E.

Comment: I tried   Promise.all(urls.map(function(each, index) {
      fetch(each).then((response) =>
      response.json()
    ).then((streamer) => streamerData.push(streamer)).then(()=>streamerInfo[index]=streamerData[index]).then(()=>{if (index === urls.length-1){this.setState({streamer: streamerData})}})},this))
  }

and it still sometimes renders blank component.. hm..

Comment: For IE8 support you need a [polyfill.](https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill)

I cleaned up the code a little and removed unnecessary variables.